# Couple of problems with custom css select box -

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need your help,

I have a custom css select box that I am creating however, 2 new issues have surfaced.

1. When a selection is made in either select dropdown box, both of the select boxes automatically have the same value:

Here is a quick capture:

[image]

2. When the drop down box is clicked on, 2 yellow boxes now appear stacked on each other as opposed to their proper box:

Here is a quick capture:

[image]

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j7fLj3g5/

The code in question:

```
function test() {

    var list = $(".select dd ul li a.selected")

    if (list.length > 1) {
        var sub_array = [];
        $.each(list, function() {
            sub_array.push($(this).data('val'))
        })

        $('.select dt a span').data('val',sub_array)
    }
    else {
        $(".select dt a span").data('val',$(".select dd ul li a.selected").data('val') )

    }

        alert($('.select dt a span').data('val') )
        //alert($('.select dt a span').html() )

}



        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".select dt a").click(function() {
                $(".select dd ul").toggle();

                $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(255,255,196)");

                //$(.select dt a span).css("background-color", "#FFF");

            });

            $(".select dd ul li a").click(function(e) {
                var text = $(this).html();

                if (e.ctrlKey) {

                    $(this).addClass('selected');

                    $(".select dt a span").html("("+ $(".select dd ul li a.selected").length+")")

                }
                else {
                    var text = $(this).html();
                    $(".select dd ul li a").removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');

                    $(".select dt a span").html(text);

                    $(".select dt a").css("background-color", "");

                    $(".select dd ul").hide();
                }
                test()

            });

            function getSelectedValue(id) {
                return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
            }

            $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
                var $clicked = $(e.target);
                if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("select"))
                    $(".select dd ul").hide();
            });



    $(".select dd ul").focusout(function() {

        $(this).css("background-color", "");

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've corrected you jQuery code to function properly. But I'm completely against using such a method to use a custom select box on your website. You should rather look at building a jQuery plugin as shown in https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/ or use an already existing plugin like select2. This way your code will be reusable and easy to maintain.

```
function test(select) {

    var list = select.find("a.selected");

    if (list.length > 1) {
        var sub_array = [];
        $.each(list, function() {
            sub_array.push($(this).data('val'))
        })

        select.find("dt a span").data('val', sub_array)
    } else {
        select.find("dt a span").data('val', select.find("dd a.selected").data('val'))

    }

    alert(select.find("dt a span").data('val'))
        //alert($('.select dt a span').html() )

}



$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".select dt a").click(function() {
        var select = $(this).closest('.select');
        select.find('ul').toggle();

        $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(255,255,196)");

        //$(.select dt a span).css("background-color", "#FFF");

    });

    $(".select dd ul li a").click(function(e) {
        var text = $(this).html();
        var select = $(this).closest('.select');

        if (e.ctrlKey) {

            $(this).addClass('selected');

            select.find('dt span').html("(" + select.find('a.selected').length + ")")

        } else {
            var text = $(this).html();
            select.find("dd a").removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            select.find("dt span").html(text);

            select.find("dt a").css("background-color", "");

            select.find("dd ul").hide();
        }
        test(select)

    });

    function getSelectedValue(id) {
        return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
    }

    $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("select"))
            $(".select dd ul").hide();
    });



    $(".select dd ul").focusout(function() {

        $(this).css("background-color", "");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you keep using a generic jquery selector inside of your click handlers. This means that when you click on one of the boxes, for example here:

```js
$(".select dt a").click(function() {
    $(".select dd ul").toggle();
```

You are calling the `toggle()` function on all instances of `.select dd ul` on the page. When you are using click handlers like this, it is usually a good idea to try and keep everything in terms of `$(this)`, which is the element that the click is handled for.

For example, the above code could be rewritten like this:

```js
$(".select dt a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings("dd").find("ul").toggle();
```

or, this:

```js
$(".select dt a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find("dd ul").toggle();
```

You need to go through your click handlers and make sure that they aren't searching the whole page, but are instead working in relation to the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is very basic answer but it will work:

replace :

```
$(".select dd ul").toggle();
```

with:

```
$(this).parent().siblings("dd").find("ul").toggle();
```